# How do you create a drawer-like (slide out) animation?

Tags: swiftui

Imagine that you have a desk with a drawer. In the closed state, you can only see the table because the drawer is beneath it. In the opened state, you see the drawer which is below the desk (because it slides down). How would I animate this such that the drawer slides out from beneath the desk in SwiftUI?

This view will be work inside a list view, so a row's dimensions must accommodate any change. So I don't know if an offset based animation would work here (as shown [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56633604/sliding-one-swiftui-view-out-from-underneath-another)). The top view (the desk) and the bottom view (the drawer) are the same size.

## Here's what I've tried...

In the code below, I use Rectangles but eventually I will use views.

### Matched Geometry Effect

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace private var animation
    @State var shown: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if !shown {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 300, height: 80, alignment: .center)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Bottom", in: animation)
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 300, height: 80, alignment: .center)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Top", in: animation)
                }
            } else {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 300, height: 80, alignment: .center)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Top", in: animation)
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 300, height: 80, alignment: .center)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Bottom", in: animation)
                }
            }
        }.onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
                shown.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Produces this...

[image: matched geometry]

### Transitions

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var shown: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Rectangle().frame(width: 300, height: 80, alignment: .center)
                .zIndex(0)
            if shown {
                Rectangle().frame(width: 300, height: 80, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .zIndex(-1)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .top))
            }
        }.onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
                shown.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: transition]

Comment: You can try my solution [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62482773/12299030)

Answer (score 0):

If the size of your drawer (`height`) is a known constant I'd go like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 80, alignment: .center)
            .offset(y: shown ? 80 : 0)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2))
        
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 300, height: 80, alignment: .center)
    }
    .onTapGesture {
        shown.toggle()
    }
}
```